# c# show Settings value in debug mode at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, settings

Hello potential Readers

**I wanted to know if one can see the stored value of a settingsobjet at runtime in debug. Like how you see the value of a variable if you hover above them.** I know i could just always make :

string a = Properties.Settings.Default.(myObjectName) and hover over a, but I want to know if there is a quicker way. I already tried Google but it didn't really show me anything that answer my question:(

[image of the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1125H.png)

(i'm using visualstudios 2015 and .Net Framework 4.5.2).

```css
Properties.Settings.Default.FileLocation = ProfileListBox.OpenFile;
//problem: I use the Filelocation quite often in my code but have to always backtrack to see what the currently assigned value for Filelocation is.
```

If you know of an other way to see the Filelocationvalue (in my case) it would be very appriciated if you could tell.

Comment: Add Watch. When in debug mode, go in the watch window, and double click in an empty cell in the firrst column. Then write Properties.Settings.Default.(myObjectName) and press enter. Now when you hit a breakpoint you can see the value.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Sadly add Watch either gave me the Error CS1061 OR CS0103 and i couldn't figure out why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My be this approach helps you with your problem:

By simply handling the `PropertyChanged` Event of the Settings.

```
        void test() {
            Settings.Default.PropertyChanged += Default_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void Default_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "MyProperty")
            {
                 var tValue = Settings.Default.PropertyValues[e.PropertyName].PropertyValue.ToString();
                 toolStripStatusLabelMessage.Text = String.Format("Property {0} changed to {1} ", e.PropertyName , tValue);
            }
        }
```